# Looking for YA horror anthology book, late 90's, early 2000's

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

I'm actually looking for the name of a particular story in this anthology. I was around 12-15 when I first stumbled across it, and to my knowledge it was popular at the time.

I've been through all three *Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark* books, and I'm pretty sure it's not in there. I'm also pretty sure it wasn't by R.L Stine.

Here's what I remember.

1. It involved an ice cream man, and a particular freezer bin in his truck he never opened for the children. One of the children, the narrator, sees or has revealed to them one long yellow braid of hair peeking out of it, but the ice cream man hastily tucks it back into the freezer bin. There was emphasis on the sound of the truck's bell, possibly "jingle jingle" or something similar.
2. It was very short, no more than four pages
   .
3. It was also on an audio book, that I think may have been packaged with the book.

Comment: What do you mean by "long yellow braid"? Like a braid of hair? Also, you might want to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Sorry, yes a long braid of hair. I'm very new to the site. I'll look at the link, thanks.

Comment: I removed the [childrens-novel] tag because from your description that doesn't seem to fit the question.